# C# MVC 4 - Action dá Error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Sou iniciante em C# MVC 4 e montei um site para fins de aprendizado.

Na página de contato do site há um formulário que envia emails automaticamente. Quando rodo ele localmente direto do Visual Studio 2013 (IIS Express) ele envia os emails tranquilamente e carrega a view de "sucesso".

Tudo certo até eu subir para o servidor da Locaweb. Agora ele dá um erro 404:

> Server Error in '/usuario/site' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /usuario/site/pt-br/Contact/Sent/
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34280

O grande problema é que as views estão todas lá. Revirei a internet e me falaram que eu poderia chamar a view com o caminho direto, mas também não funcionou :(

Neste caso eu não entendi se o que ele não está achando é a `Action` ou a `View` do `return View()`.

Segue a action que está no meu controller da página de contato:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Sent(Formulario formulario)
        {
            if (formulario.Validar())
            {
                try
                {
                    var mensagem = formulario.Mensagem.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
                    var smtpUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpUri"];
                    var smtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]);
                    var emailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailTo"];

                    var client = new SmtpClient(smtpUri, smtpPort)
                    {
                        EnableSsl = false,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("meuEmail", "minhaSenha")
                    };
                    var mail = new MailMessage("meuEmail, emailTo);
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Subject = String.Format("Contato via site - Página: {0}", formulario.Pagina);
                    mail.Body = mensagem;
                    client.Send(mail);

                    return View("~/Views/Contact/Sent.cshtml");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return View("~/Views/Contact/Error.cshtml");
                }
            }

            return Json(new {success = false});
        }
```

Meu RouteConfig.cs:

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("i18n", "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, language = "pt-br" },
                new { language = "en|pt|es|pt-br|en-us" }
                );

            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
    }
```

Na verdade o `"/usuario/site"` é porque o site está no ar dentro de uma subpasta pois não quero que fique no ar com erros ainda. Ele está funcionando tranquilamente em todas páginas, menos quando tento enviar um email pela página de contato.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?! Obrigado!!

Comment: Poderia colocar as rotas que está usando aqui?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com as configurações de rota, Paulo. Obrigado!

Comment: Resolvi meu problema adicionando uma barra ("/") ao final da URL de chamada!

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi, esta view será renderizada apenas se o verbo utilizado for o POST. tente adicionar o atributo [HttpGet] e publique novamente para ver se funciona.

Uma outra coisa me chamou a atenção na sua url: /usuario/site/pt-br/Contact/Sent/

Este /pt-br está correto?

Geralmente utilizamos algo mais simplificado como "http://www.site.com.br/NomeDoController/NomeDaAction"

no seu caso, acho que seria /Contact (Controller)
e a Action /Sent

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Thiago! Na verdade eu quero usar POST mesmo... E como localmente está funcinonando não vejo porque trocar para GET só por esse motivo. De qualquer jeito, atualizei a pergunta com explicações sobre a URL, se puder conferir ficarei muito grato! abs

Comment: Faça o seguinte, crie uma nova Action neste mesmo controller que retorne um Content: public ActionResult Teste()
        { return Content("TESTE");}

Comment: e tente acessar a url: www.seusite.com.br/usuario/site/pt-br/Contact/Teste

Comment: www.seusite.com.br/usuario/site/pt-br/Contact/Teste ou www.seusite.com.br/site/pt-br/Contact/Teste ou www.seusite.com.br/site/pt-br/Contact/Teste uma destas deve retornar o conteúdo www.seusite.com.br/pt-br/Contact/Teste

Comment: Consegui acessar via http://meusite.com.br/usuario/site/Contact/Teste/ 
coloquei um método de  GET também que só renderiza a view, e no metodo de POST coloquei um RedirectToAction chamando o método de GET. Agora a view está sendo mostrada, mas o email não é enviado :(

Comment: já tentou trocar de smtp? Tenta com sendgrid....deve funcionar